# Why am I getting one date that is different from what I am creating?

Tags: angular, typescript, date, object

I am using angular to make some dates with some amounts and found my problem was the first date would be off on one of my sets so I set it up as simply hard coding the random data in and found this first date would was not the date I told it to create.

```
function MakeData() {
  let w =  {
    asset: [
      { date: new Date(2022, 5, 1), amount: 50 },
      { date: new Date(2022, 7, 1), amount: 55 },
      { date: new Date(2022, 8, 1), amount: 60 },
      { date: new Date(2022, 11, 1), amount: 70 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 0, 1), amount: 71 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 1, 1), amount: 80 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 2, 1), amount: 82 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 3, 1), amount: 83 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 4, 1), amount: 81 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 5, 1), amount: 85 },
    ],
    debt: [
      { date: new Date(2022, 6, 1), amount: 49 },
      { date: new Date(2022, 9, 1), amount: 44 },
      { date: new Date(2022, 10, 1), amount: 43 },
      { date: new Date(2022, 11, 1), amount: 38 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 0, 1), amount: 35 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 1, 1), amount: 36 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 3, 1), amount: 38 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 4, 1), amount: 35 },
      { date: new Date(2023, 5, 1), amount: 31 },
    ]
  }
  console.log("Arrays in Mock" )
  console.log(w.asset )
  console.log(   w.debt)
  return w;
}


export const MockWorthDebtData = MakeData();
```

The first date in assets array should be 2022 but comes up as 2023.
I get in the console this:

```
Array(10) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { date: Date Sun Jan 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time), amount: 50 }
​
1: Object { date: Date Mon Aug 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time), amount: 55 }
​
2: Object { date: Date Thu Sep 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time), amount: 60 }
​
3: Object { date: Date Thu Dec 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time), amount: 70 }
​
4: Object { date: Date Sun Jan 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time), amount: 71 }
​
5: Object { date: Date Wed Feb 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time), amount: 80 }
​
6: Object { date: Date Wed Mar 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time), amount: 82 }
​
7: Object { date: Date Sat Apr 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time), amount: 83 }
​
8: Object { date: Date Mon May 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time), amount: 81 }
​
9: Object { date: Date Thu Jun 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time), amount: 85 }
​
length: 10
​
Array(9) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { date: Date Fri Jul 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time), amount: 49 }
​
1: Object { date: Date Sat Oct 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time), amount: 44 }
​...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the arrow like text corruption on `w[asset]` assign:

> asset: [
> `-->`     { date: new Date(2022, 5, 1),

the month in javascript is 0-indexed so w values are:

```
[
  { date: 2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 50 },
  { date: 2022-08-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 55 },
  { date: 2022-09-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 60 },
  { date: 2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 70 },
  { date: 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 71 },
  { date: 2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 80 },
  { date: 2023-03-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 82 },
  { date: 2023-04-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 83 },
  { date: 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 81 },
  { date: 2023-06-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 85 }
]
[
  { date: 2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 49 },
  { date: 2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 44 },
  { date: 2022-11-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 43 },
  { date: 2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 38 },
  { date: 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 35 },
  { date: 2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 36 },
  { date: 2023-04-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 38 },
  { date: 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 35 },
  { date: 2023-06-01T00:00:00.000Z, amount: 31 }
]
```

Comment: That is not in the program. It was just added to show the mistake.